# how to insert data like reply000000000000123 or communicate00000000000000000123 into sql? which support auto increment of the number starting from 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a requirement to insert into a sql table column, where data should be in the format mentioned. how to achieve that? i am new to sql

Comment: Those are strings so you can't auto increment them.

Comment: is there any way out of it ? using php

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense to have two fields - one for the string part and one for the number. Do you really need all those zeros though?? I suppose you could pad the number at the time when you select and join it to the string for output

Comment: Depending on dbms, you can have an autoincrement column for the integer part, and a virtual/computed column for the desired result. Or use triggers.

Comment: Nobody, who knows anything about databases, would require you to use that format. Simply use a normal [auto increment field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). It will work out fine.

Comment: i am using sql. the problem is that i shouldnot run out of numbers. reply and communicate are two user interactions n i am storing in table in a single column.

Comment: We know you're using SQL. That wasn't the question - you were asked what specific DBMS (Database Management System) you are using? There are many versions of SQL - e.g. MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, SqLite, and others. What you can do to solve this depends a bit on which one you use, as they all have different extra features beyond the basic SQL support

Comment: A BigInt goes to 18.446.744.073.709.551.615 numbers (mysql unsigned ) or 9.223.372.036.854.775.807 (SQL) . Should be sufficient.

Comment: i absolutely have no idea. i am a front-end developer. becuase of lack of resources , i have to create the app alone. using mysql workbench. thats all i know.

Comment: It's MySQL then. Workbench is the application many people use to maintain and set up a mySQL server. Even if you're there on your own, the internet is your friend, you can find out what the tools you're using are about.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want the ids of a table to be integers -- and auto-incremented integers are very convenient:

```
create table t (
    t_id int auto_increment primary key,
    . . . 
);
```

Why are integers a good choice? Here are some reasons:

- They are a fixed length of 4 bytes.
- Fixed length and shorter columns are somewhat more efficient in indexes.
- Foreign keys would use the same type and integers are generally shorter than strings.
- They are pretty easy to recognize and type in.

If you want this formatted as something like `t00000`, then you can use a view:

```
create table v_t as
    select t.*, concat(t, lpad(t_id, 5, '0')) as t_id_str
    from t;
```

If you want separate automatically enumerated values in a single table . . . Well, I can say that many, many databases have been created without using them. If you really, really wanted this representation in a single table, then you would need to define triggers. However, I suspect that your data model is off, because it suggests that a single table would contain multiple different entities.